# Como anteceder un elemento en javascript DOM?

Tags: javascript

Al cliquear dentro del div, se muestra los 10 valores de un array, pero como puedo ubicarlo en el HTML, **antes** del titulo

> Shift() array

y **después** del título

> Push() array

***sin modificar el HTML NI EL CSS3***

```js
/*      Multiple methods in arrays

  Learning javascript and reinforcing
  my knowledge!

      ====> Eduardo Sebastián <====
*/

// Re-usable var's
var cc = []; // Main array
var div = document.getElementById('array');
var t = "";
var w = "";
var c = "";

// End 

// Add element at first w/ push()
div.addEventListener("click", pushing);
function pushing() {
for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
  cc.push(i);
 w = document.getElementById("array");
 c = document.createElement("B");
 c.style.color = "white";
 c.style.textAlign = "center";
 t = document.createTextNode((i==0 ? "Push in array: " : "")+i);
 c.appendChild(t);
 w.appendChild(c);
  
}
  }
```

```css
#array {
  
  background-color: pink;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
  
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width">
  <title>JS Bin</title>
</head>
<body>
  
  
  <div id="array">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Push() array</h3>
     <h3 style="text-align: center;">Shift() array</h3>
    
  </div>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: No queda muy claro qué es lo que quieres hacer. Por favor añade una descripción más detallada del comportamiento esperado y de por qué el código que compartes no funciona.

Comment: Es decir, quieres que arriba de Push() array se imprima el arreglo normal, y abajo de Shift() array se imprima el arreglo al revés?

Comment: ya me lo resolvieron lixus

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Si lo tengo bien, desea insertar esa salida de Javascript antes del primer título **`h3`** `Push() array` y también después de lo segundo título **`h3`** `Shift() array`.

Se es esto puedes hacerlo de la seguiente manera:

```js
/*      Multiple methods in arrays

  Learning javascript and reinforcing
  my knowledge!

      ====> Eduardo Sebastián <====
*/

// Re-usable var's
var cc = []; // Main array
var div = document.getElementById('array');
var t = "";
var w = "";
var c = "";

// End 

// Add element at first w/ push()
div.addEventListener("click", pushing);
function pushing() {
    for(let i=0; i<=10; i++) {
        cc.push(i);
        w = document.getElementById("array");
        c = document.createElement("B");
        c.style.color = "white";
        c.style.textAlign = "center";
        t = document.createTextNode((i==0 ? "Push in array: " : "")+i);

        c.appendChild(t);

        // Crear 2 nuevas variables para obtener el primer y último hijo del elemento
        nuevoW = w.childNodes[i]; // Esto se usó desta manera para que no invierte la orden cuando se imprime con "firstchild"
        nuevoWultimo = w.lastChild;

        // Inserta "c" antes de "nuevoW" que es el primer niño de id array
        nuevoW.parentNode.insertBefore(c, nuevoW);
        
        // Inserta "c" después de "nuevoWultimo" que es lo ultimo niño de id array
        nuevoW.parentNode.insertBefore(c.cloneNode(true), nuevoWultimo.nextSibling);

    }
}
```

```css
#array {
  background-color: pink;
  width: 250px;
  height: 250px;
  overflow: scroll;
  margin: 0 auto;
}
h1,h2,h3,h4,h5,h6 {
  color: blue;
}
```

```html
<div id="array">
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Push() array</h3>
    <h3 style="text-align: center;">Shift() array</h3>
</div>
```

Comment: La solución no muestra `shift()`

Comment: No sé por qué alguien Voto negativo en mi respuesta, pero siempre es bueno decir la razón en los comentarios para entender y así hacer las modificaciones necesarias en la respuesta si es un punto válido.

Comment: @Lixus En la solución la salida es antes y después de ambos. Haga clic en el botón de prueba amigo

Comment: Ahhhhhhhhh @Lixus , ahora lo tengo! La gente está pensando que el quiere algo más. Cuando lo único que quiere es imprimir esa salida antes y después de ambos los textos. Esos son sólo los nombres del título y es más confuso debido a eso. Yo seguí el principio del título y después la descripción fue más fácil de entender.

Comment: Si ambos títulos son confusos sobre si quiere ambos push, o push y shift